# Tag synonym request: [swipe-gesture] and [swipe]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I'd like to propose [swipe-gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swipe-gesture) as a synonym of [swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swipe).

Current data:

#### swipe-gesture

467 questions, 0 synonyms

> Swipe is a gesture that involves touching a touchscreen or trackpad, translating the finger in one direction across the screen or pad, and removing the finger. It is commonly used as a discrete scrolling gesture (for example, go to the next picture).

#### swipe

2,586 questions, 0 synonyms

> A quick motion gesture across a touchscreen.